# MVC3 JSON Return to Edit Page

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have some javascript code that sends data to my controller:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#newGrade").click(function () {
                var newGradeName = $("#newGradeName").val();
                var newGradeValue = $("#newGradeValue").val();
                var vSchoolID = $("#SchoolID").val();

                if (newGradeName != null && newGradeValue != null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("NewGrade", "School")',
                        data: { gradeName: newGradeName, gradeValue: newGradeValue, schoolID: vSchoolID },
                        type: 'POST',
                        traditional: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status)
                                window.location = data.route;
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult NewGrade(String gradeName, Int32 gradeValue, Guid schoolID)
    {
        School school = schoolRepository.GetByID(schoolID);
        school.Grades.Add(
            new Grade
            {
                GradeID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = gradeName,
                NumericalValue = gradeValue
            });
        schoolRepository.Update(school);
        schoolRepository.Save();
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var json = new { status = true, route = Url.RouteUrl(new { action = "Edit", id = schoolID }) };
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My issue now is I want to return to my Edit page (possibly refreshing the page, but not the data, or just refresh the entire page), but my Edit page takes an ID (schoolID). Shown here when pressing the button to get to the Edit page:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "School", new { id = Model.School.SchoolID })"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `window.location.href` and see what happens.

```
success: function(data) {
                        if (data.status)
                            window.location.href = data.route;
                    },
```

This should work fine assuming you are getting a `JSON` reponse from your action method like

```
{"status":"true","route":"/School/Edit/1"}
```

where 1 is the ID of new record.

Comment: My response is: `{ status = true, route = "/Administrator/School/Edit/6cc2bbe1-4a4a-4c08-a1f1-001a25e9b988" }`

Comment: @WesleyPattison: What is the problem then ? is window.location.href not working ?

Comment: Nope, it's returning me back to: http://localhost:5591/Administrator/School with the changed javascript: success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status)
                                window.location.href = data.route;
                        }

I've looked in the Chrome Debugger and I see my changes to the javascript too.

Comment: Ah, looks like I either A) needed to change my <button> to include type="button" or rebuild my project (silly me). Thanks!